# Does everybody steal?

Tags: gezel-stealing

I remember reading a quote, attributed to the Talmud, that essentially says "everybody steals".  I doubt it's genuine, and if it is, it's probably heavily qualified, but I thought I'd ask: Does this quote ring a bell?

Comment: When a question like this shows up in HNQ, it doesn't exactly work to dispel certain negative stereotypes about Jews.

Comment: @nick012000 -- Why?  The Talmud is making general statements about human nature, not about Jews in particular, and obviously does not approve of these behaviors.

Comment: Sometimes statements about human nature can be seen to reveal more about the person saying them than humanity in general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [Baba Batra 165a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.165a.2?lang=bi&with=Shemirat%20HaLashon&lang2=en) :

> אמר רב יהודה אמר רב רוב בגזל ומיעוט בעריות והכל בלשון הרע

> Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: The majority of people succumb to sin with regard to robbery, and a minority of people succumb to sin with regard to sexual matters, and everyone succumbs to sin with regard to malicious speech.

But Rashbam writes:

> רוב בגזל - רוב בני אדם חשודין על הגזל כעין גזל שמורין להתירא במשא ובמתן לעכב איש מריוח הראוי לו לחבירו:

That is, the majority is suspected about stealing when they thinks it's their due, when they are teaching to themselves that's it is ok, as in business.

Comment: Thank you, sir!  I knew I could trust my memory...